# How to create video from images on Windows 8 (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, video-processing, avi, directshow.net

I'm working on creating media file from list of image files. On desktop we have different ways to stich image files into video (AviFile lib, FFMPEG and DirectShow with managed wrapers).
Is there a way to use sme of this libraries on WinRT or may be another solution exists?

**UPDATE**

I found solution. WinRT component to create a video file using Media Foundation
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx

Comment: You would need to rewrite those wrappers.

Comment: Is this libraries works on ARM processors?

Comment: You will have to rewrite them in order to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should be doable using Media Foundation, but I have not done that myself. They did mention some APIs for these though at //Build/ - check this one: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-106

Comment: I think it's right way, but I still can't find solution. I can't create stream from images.

Comment: Watch the video carefully. I remember someone asking almost that same question and they mentioning some specific API calls to use there.